# How to calculate the overlap area?

Tags: math

There are two overlapping rectangles and I need to calculate the overlap area (width and height). Please this image:

[image]

Comment: This sort of question seems better suited for the mathematics stack exchange website.

Comment: It's a common programming interview question.

Comment: I believe this should not be closed as offtopic. It is a valid issue related to programming, and it can have a definite answer (it already has one).

Answer (score 10):

If rectangle r1 is at x1,y1 and have width w1,h1, and likewise rectangle r2 is at x2,y2 with width w2 and height h2, then you can find the left edge of the red region like  (Assuming the widths and heights of both rectangles are positive so the positions are the bottom left corners):

```
left = max(x1, x2);
```

Similarly for the right, bottom and top:

```
right = min(x1 + w1, x2 + w2);
bottom = max(y1, y2);
top = min(y1 + h1, y2 + h2);
```

The size of the overlapping area is

```
height = top - bottom 
width = right - left.
```

If either if these is negative, there is no overlap.

Comment: I used this to help me solve a programming programming. It may not have "code" in it; but it does provide algorithm- an important part of coding.

Comment: May not be the right site for this kind of question, but still helped me put together a nice little package for signal processing. +1 For a solid answer