# Calculating the overlap of cells

Tags: overlap

I'm trying to arrange cells of different sizes randomly and then calculate the overlapping area between the different cells. So the overlaps can be any of the following and perhaps some others too. I'm doing a one to one comparison between the different cells to check overlap and calculate it.

[image]

So I have to detect the overlap and calculate the area in green. Suppose I've named the cells as cell 1 and cell 2, with the value of the left side as x1 and value of the right side as x2. The bottom side as y1 and the top side as y2. So this is kind of my code right now, but don't seem to be covering all the parts of it.
Considering the cell in black as cell1 and the one in red as cell2,

```
if (cell1.x2 > cell2.x1)
{
    if(cell1.y2 > 
     if ((cell1.y2 > cell2.y1) && (cell2.y1 >= cell1.y1))
    {
    if(cell1.y2 > cell2.y2)
    {
         if (cell1.x2 > cell2.x2)
        {   
            Area = cell2.h * cell2.w;
            continue;
        }
        Area = cell2.h * cell2.x1 - cell1.x2);
        continue;
        }

    Area = cell1.x2 - cell1.x1) * cell1.y2 - cell2.y1);
    continue;
    }
```

I think I'm missing some conditions, but this looks like a lot of if statements. What would be an ideal way to calculate the areas ?

Comment: What language? And have you referred to this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143951/551093

Comment: The programming is in C. The link you've given me refers to only a specific example. I'm trying to program it to detect the overlaps and then calculate it.

Comment: What do you mean? The code in that link calculates the area of 2 overlapping rectangles, which is _exactly_ what you asked for. It also detects whether there is an overlap or not (negative means no overlap). Just run it in a nested for loop - ie, run each rectangle against every other rectangle.